# Simplificação de código

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou com o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<p:menuButton value="#{messages['relatorio']}">
                    <p:menuitem value="PDF" update="painelRelatorioResumoExpedicaoDesembarque" oncomplete="gerarRelatorio();" id="commandButtonGerarRelatorio" action="#{executarServicoController.executarServicoHelper}" ajax="true">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.parametros.paramsHelper.idUnidadeResponsavelCarga}" value="#{appHelper.idUnidadeResponsavelCorrente}" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.parametros.paramsHelper.idUnidadeOperacaoCarga}" value="#{appHelper.idUnidadeOperacaoCorrente}" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.serviceBean}" value="modalService" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.serviceMethod}" value="obterDadosRelatoriosMovimentacaoImportacao" />
                    <f:param name="tipoRelatorio" value="pdf" />
                    </p:menuitem>
                    <p:menuitem value="XLS" update="painelRelatorioResumoExpedicaoDesembarque" oncomplete="gerarRelatorio();" id="commandButtonGerarRelatorios" action="#{executarServicoController.executarServicoHelper}" ajax="true">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.parametros.paramsHelper.idUnidadeResponsavelCarga}" value="#{appHelper.idUnidadeResponsavelCorrente}" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.parametros.paramsHelper.idUnidadeOperacaoCarga}" value="#{appHelper.idUnidadeOperacaoCorrente}" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.serviceBean}" value="modalService" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.serviceMethod}" value="obterDadosRelatoriosMovimentacaoImportacao" />
                    <f:param name="tipoRelatorio" value="xls" />
                    </p:menuitem>
                </p:menuButton>
```

Reparem que há 2 `<p:menuitem>` onde a única diferença é que no `<f:param` eu defino o value diferente. Existe alguma maneira de simplificar e deixar tudo em um bloco por exemplo ?

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isto você precisará de duas coisas:

- Uma lista para iterar dentro do Bean contendo as opções necessárias;
- Um c:forEach (ui:repeat não funcionará devido às limitações do componente p:menuButton) dentro do xhtml para iterar a lista incluida anteriormente.

Sendo assim, para incluir a lista no bean você pode fazer assim:

```
public List<String> getTiposRelatorio() {
    List<String> tipos = new ArrayList<>();
    tipos.add("PDF");
    tipos.add("XLS");
    return tipos;
}
```

Depois, iterar esta lista dentro do elemento p:menuButton incluindo as variáveis da iteração, desta forma:
- Obs1: substituir a variável "nome_do_seu_bean" pelo nome do seu bean;
- Obs2: Não se esqueça de importar o namespace "c" no topo do xhtml (xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core").

```
<p:menuButton value="#{messages['relatorio']}">
    <c:forEach list="#{nome_do_seu_bean.tiposRelatorio}" var="tipo">
        <p:menuitem value="#{tipo}" update="painelRelatorioResumoExpedicaoDesembarque" oncomplete="gerarRelatorio();" id="commandButtonGerarRelatorio" action="#{executarServicoController.executarServicoHelper}" ajax="true">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.parametros.paramsHelper.idUnidadeResponsavelCarga}" value="#{appHelper.idUnidadeResponsavelCorrente}" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.parametros.paramsHelper.idUnidadeOperacaoCarga}" value="#{appHelper.idUnidadeOperacaoCorrente}" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.serviceBean}" value="modalService" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executarServicoPreenchendoParametrosExecutarForm.serviceMethod}" value="obterDadosRelatoriosMovimentacaoImportacao" />
            <f:param name="tipoRelatorio" value="#{tipo.toLowerCase()}" />
        </p:menuitem>
    </c:forEach>
</p:menuButton>
```

Imagino que esta abordagem irá resolver seu problema, boa sorte!

Obs: Esta solução não é a indicada nestes casos. Segundo a documentação do PrimeFaces, para criar itens dinâmicos dentro de componentes de menu você deveria fazer diretamente pelo Bean, criando os componentes dinamicamente, mas pelo fato de você estar incluindo vários passThroughAttribute preferi não utilizar esta abordagem.